# Direct3d9 Create a Const RECT for Present()

Tags: directx, directx-9

Im just started programming with Direct3d9

so

i want just create a Rect

mydevice->->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

i dont want use NULL in Present fonction because a want create a rectangle for my surface Direct3d9. 
i want create a window with botton and direct3d surface like 3Dsmax (4 surface and botton in left), so please how i can create this Rectangle ?

Rect r;
...
r.top;
r.left;
...
this rectangle return a LONG value and i need a Const RECT that i can set it in Present() fonction, so please how i can do that ?

Comment: do you want to draw a rectangle or just create a rect structure?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, you don't need to pass a rect to function [present](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), unless your swap chain was created with D3DSWAPEFFECT_COPY.

If you want just want to draw subwindows like 3ds max, you should try multiple view or multiple windows in DirectX.

You won't specify any geometry in present, this function just present the content in backbuffer to the display, you should prepare everything you want to draw before calling this function.